# Access sql database from LAN

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

my two computers are connected via LAN. computer1(192.168.0.56) contains the ffollowing program

```
import MySQLdb
db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","testDB")
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER")
sql="""CREATE TABLE USER(
   ID  INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
   )"""
cursor.execute(sql)
db.close()
```

from another another computer(192.168.0.4) i want to insert value to the table

```
import MySQLdb
db= MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.56","root","pass","testDB")
cursor=db.cursor()
sql="""INSERT INTO USER(USERNAME,
   PASSWORD)
   VALUES('admin','12345'),
         ('abc','123'),
         ('user3','5687')"""
try:
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
print ("Data is inserted into database")
except:
db.rollback()
print ("Data cann't be updated")
db.close()
```

error: access denied root@192.168.0.4

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use port
as,
db= MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.56:8080","root","pass","testDB")
```

Comment: check which port your mysql is running on, use that port! all the best :)

Comment: Now try this one (with port 3306 as default mysql port)

db= MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.56:3306","root","pass","testDB")

Comment: MySQLdb.connect("192.168.0.56:3306","root","pass","testDB") is showing  OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.0.56:3306' (0)")

Comment: boss, can you please check your mysql port then integrate same !

Comment: when i create another user then it works fine. root is not accesiable

Answer (score 0):

You have not added port, so try adding port first.
Syntax for connecting mysql is 
MySQLdb.connect(host,userName,passWord,databaseName,port)
Still if its not accessible then , 
You need to change mysql server access settings from localhost to "*".
Have a look of following link : 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-connection-from-other-machine/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new user who can access to this database with the host 192.168.0.4 or %, because by default root can be used only from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are permitted to connect that database from computer 192.168.0.4. You need to grant access to root user @ 192.168.0.4

To confirm, please check the current user and hosts who have access to login into the database using query:

```
SELECT `Host`, `User` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

If you want to give access to another user then use `GRANT` command in sql as:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database_name> TO <user>@<ipadress>
```

This should resolve your problem